# "Codebase is assembled with Composer instead of Drush" (but it wasn't!) message

Tags: 7, drush

I'm using D7 and I'm seeing the following error message any time I try to use Drush to install a module:

> This codebase is assembled with Composer instead of Drush. Use `composer update` and `composer require` instead of `drush pm-updatecode` and `drush pm-download`. You may override this error by using the --pm-force option.

Why does Drush generate that error message? The website was not built using Composer (though there are other Composer-based Drupal project on the same web server).

FWIW, using the `--pm-force` option works just fine. I would just understand the reason of that error message.

Comment: What version of Drush?

Comment: Is there a composer.json file?

Comment: The website with the drush message does not have a compser.json file. Another Drupal website located in a different directory does not get the above message. Both sites are using the same version of Drush (version 8.1.15).

Answer (score 2):

It comes from a command file like [policy.drush.inc](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/527cd79326177d7a6d48df6308cf9efa2f6338df/drush/policy.drush.inc).

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm still trying to figure out why one website is generating the message and another is not, when as far I can tell they are otherwise identical (same version of Drupal, same version of Drush).